# nginx 413 when trying to upload a to a private docker registry

Tags: docker, proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, http-status-code-413

I'm setting up a private docker registry, which I'm accessing via an nginx proxy.
Am able to connect to the registry, but cannot push an image to it.

Here's the response that I'm getting from the docker Push command.

```
  error parsing HTTP 413 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "<html>\r\n<head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
```

The proxy that I'm running is using nginx, and takes care of the SSL Stuff.

Here's my nginx.conf file

```
 worker_processes 1;
 
 events { worker_connections 1024; }
 
 http {
     client_max_body_size 0;
     sendfile on;
 
     upstream registry {
         server linux.lan.local:5000;
     }
 
     proxy_set_header   Host $host;
     proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
 
     server {
         listen 80;
 
         server_name     registry.cjdawson.com;
 
         location / {
             proxy_pass         http://linux.lan.local:5000;
 
             proxy_redirect     off;
         }
     }
 
     server {
         listen 443;
 
         server_name     registry.cjdawson.com;
 
         location / {
             proxy_pass         http://linux.lan.local:5000;
             proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header   Connection "Upgrade";
             proxy_redirect     off;
         }
     }
 }
```

As you can see, I do have the entry

```
     client_max_body_size 0;
```

which is supposed to be the normal answer to being able to upload large files.  indeed, I'm using this successfully with other services that I'm running behind other proxies.   (The nginx proxy is running as in Kubernetes as an ingress, which takes care of the SSL Stuff for me.)

In summary, I'm able to log into the registry via the proxy using the docker login command.
The push is failing to upload the image.

Any ideas?

In case someone asks about my docker registry setup, here's my docker-compose.

```
 version: '3.1'

 services:
   registry-server:
     image: registry:2.8.2
     restart: always
     ports:
       - 5000:5000
     environment:
       REGISTRY_AUTH: htpasswd
       REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH: /auth/htpasswd
       REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM: Registry Realm
     volumes:
       - ./registry/data:/var/lib/registry
       - ./registry/config.yml:/etc/docker/registry/config.yml:ro
       - ./registry/auth:/auth
     container_name: registry-server
 
   registry-ui:
     image: joxit/docker-registry-ui:main
     restart: always
     ports:
       - 8080:80
     environment:
       - REGISTRY_URL=http://linux.lan.local:5000
       - DELETE_IMAGES=true
     container_name: registry-ui
```

So what's supposed to be happening is as follows....

Docker on the client connected to registry.cjdawson.com    using SSL (port 443)
The encryption is removed by the proxy, and the body is forwarded on to linux.lan.local:5000 which is running the registry.

update:
I decided to see if I can bypass the proxy as a test, and can confirm that images can be uploaded successfully to the registy when sent directly to linux.lan.local.   However, it's not internet facing and I have to tweak my docker install to be able to interact via http.